# How to perform two actions when the back button is pressed with jQuery Mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

I have a back button on a navigation bar at the top of the page enabled with:

```
<div data-role="page" id="chat" data-add-back-btn="true">
```

I would like to call a javascript method when the back button is clicked, but without removing the back functionality. I was trying to create my own back button and then call to `javascript:history.back(1)` but I prefer to keep the original button.

Thanks

Comment: Question is not clear. Please explain clearly.

Comment: Have you looked into the [events jQuery mobile provides](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/api/events.html)?  Specifically, the "Page change events" and "Page transition events" sections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot prioritize jQuery events, and jQuery events stack. So you have two options, one is to daisy chain your ordering of events (callbacks), the other is to remove the default behavior and overwrite the event.

What you might want to do is `event.preventDefault()` followed by your code and then do a `history.back(1)`:

```
$(<backbutton selector>).click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  alert('this is a test');
  history.go(-1);
});
```

Comment: It's not the browser back button, it's the button created by jQueryMobile http://jquerymobile.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/back-button.png

Comment: oh, thank you for correcting me pablobart - I'll check it out and delete this answer

Comment: the problem was that the button was created by the jQuery Mobile api so I didn't know how to access it until I have the generated html. I then used $('[data-rel="back"]').live('click',function... to capture the click event. Thanks!